# What is context Id of cdt plugin?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt

I want to know the context ID of CDT.

The Context ID used in:

```
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getHelpSystem().displayHelpResource(cdt_context_id);
```

Any way to find the context id of various help contents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use Eclipse Plug-in spy for viewing the details of menu, toolbar contributions etc. Plugin -spy window will show all the details of the selected UI element like which plugin is contributing the element , which class  etc ..In bottom side the corresponding help context id's will be shown.

```
To inspect the current selection, press ALT-SHIFT-F1
To inspect menus, press ALT-SHIFT-F2 and then select the menu item
```

Details will be shown in the below link

http://www.eclipse.org/pde/incubator/spy/